# can i make this work without using __constructor

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

i was working on something else slightly similar to this problem. what im trying to do is to make a class with private properties (or something don't know what exactly call this) and privately stored in a class and then make an inheritance like this:

(i want to clarify my explanation further more but my vocabular in programming is very limited)

```
 <?php
        class Fruit {
          private $name;
          private $color;
          public function patients($name, $color) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->color = $color;
          }
         
          public function intro() {
            echo "The fruit is {$this->name} and the color is {$this->color}.";
          }
        }
        
        // Strawberry is inherited from Fruit
        class Strawberry extends Fruit {
          public function message() {
            echo $this->intro();
          }
          
        }
    
    $strawberry = new Strawberry("Strawberry", "red");
    $strawberry->message();
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You should use the methods you declared and not use the constructor (`new Strawberry("Strawberry", "red");`) if you haven't set it up and don't want to use it):

```
<?php
class Fruit {
  private $name;
  private $color;
  public function describe($name, $color) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->color = $color;
  }

  public function intro() {
    echo "The fruit is {$this->name} and the color is {$this->color}.";
  }
}

// Strawberry is inherited from Fruit
class Strawberry extends Fruit {
  public function message() {
    echo $this->intro();
  }
}
```

Renamed your method `patients()` to `describe()` to be more fitting. Removed your method `assignPatient()` since you didn't use it and it basically did the same what `describe()` does.
You can now use

```
$strawberry = new Strawberry();
$strawberry->describe("Strawberry", "red");
$strawberry->message();
```

to output "*The fruit is Strawberry and the color is red.*".

You could in fact also remove your `message()` method and call `intro()` instead:

```
$strawberry = new Strawberry();
$strawberry->describe("Strawberry", "red");
$strawberry->intro();
```